# Cursor selection stops when it reaches to custom inline node

Tags: vue.js, tiptap, prose-mirror

I have a signature node like below -

```js
export default Node.create({
  name: "SignatureNode",
  inline: true,
  group: "inline",
  atom: false,

  addAttributes() {
    return {
      content: {
        default: "",
        parseHTML: (el) =>
          el.getAttribute("content") ?? el.getAttribute("data-content"),
      },
      signId: {
        default: "",
        parseHTML: (el) =>
          el.getAttribute("signId") ?? el.getAttribute("data-signId"),
      },
    };
  },

  parseHTML() {
    return [
      {
        tag: "signature-node",
      },
      {
        tag: "div",
        getAttrs: (node) =>
          (node as HTMLElement).classList.contains("signature-node") && null,
      },
    ];
  },
  addCommands() {
    return {
      addSign:
        (options) =>
        ({ chain, state }) => {
          // ...
        },
    };
  },

  renderHTML({ HTMLAttributes }) {
    const div = document.createElement("div");

    // Create app for getting article component html
    const app = createApp(SignatureNode, {
      content: HTMLAttributes.content,
      signId: HTMLAttributes.signId,
    });

    const mounted = app.mount(div);
    const html = mounted.$el;

    // Unmount app for performance
    app.unmount();

    return html;

  },

  addNodeView() {
    return VueNodeViewRenderer(SignatureNodeWrapper);
  },
});
```

When i try to move my cursor from outer text to custom node it moves perfectly but when move my cursor while selecting some content then it stops at the custom node starting point.

Here is the gif about that -

[image]

i have tried adding contenteditable to my `NodeViewWrapper` and it works somewhat but it snaps the selection cursor to end of the custom node and doesn't select each element inside the custom node.

```html
  <NodeViewWrapper class="node" contenteditable="true">
    <SignatureNode
      :content="node.attrs.content"
      :sign-id="node.attrs.signId"
      :update-attributes="updateAttributes"
    />
  </NodeViewWrapper>
```

Comment: Can you also share the `renderHTML` method from your Node? see if you have a so-called "hole" (represented with 0) while rendering the HTML (e.g. https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/blob/develop/packages/extension-table-row/src/table-row.ts#L27)

Comment: Added renderHTML code.

Comment: You are not supposed to use the `renderHTML` like this, you need to add the render props in a predefined format that is supported by tiptap, you can see the example in extensions present in the tiptap repository [here](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/tree/develop/packages).  Could be worthwhile to check the custom extension documentation here - https://tiptap.dev/guide/custom-extensions;